# Actionbarsherlock IcsSpinner - width always set to widest items

Tags: android, spinner, actionbarsherlock

I'm using Actionbarsherlock and want to use a custom actionbar layout, but still want a navigation list. As a result I am including an IcsSpinner widget. However, the width is always as big as the largest item, and this is not desired. I broke it out of the actionbar to debug and still got the same results:

[image: Short Text]

[image]

Fragment Code

```
public class TestFragment extends SherlockFragment {
private final String[] testStrings = {"Short","Not so long text"};
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_layout, container, false);
    IcsSpinner spinner = (IcsSpinner)view.findViewById(R.id.test_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
             R.layout.spiner_test_row, R.id.spinner_text, testStrings);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    return(view);
    }
}
```

test_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsSpinner
    android:id="@+id/test_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

R.layout.spinner_test_row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Changing to standard Spinner (on gingerbread emulator) works fine:

[image]

[image]

Any Suggestions?

Comment: @JakeWharton Wharton How do you not use internal and get the above gingerbread result with com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsSpinner?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This appears to be the default behavior of the IcsSpinner component within ActionBarSherlock, even when running Honeycomb+ version of Android - e.g. Square Wallet on my ICS device.

Jake has suggested not using the IcsSpinner component, but without it there is no way simple way to use a custom actionbar layout and maintain the Navigation List UI. Unless Jake can suggest and alternative I will continue to use it, making sure do full testing upon future releases of his great library.

Comment: So are you saying there is no way to position the triangle spinner to the width of the selectedNavigationItem?

Comment: @taraloca Correct, the IcsSpinner is always as wide as the longest item. You can see this in Square Wallet, written by Jake Wharton himself.